# Metadata extract in Java?

Tags: java, metadata, media

I have `.mov` files that I want to extract **metadata** from. I have tried `mediainfo`, but can't get the start time and end time. How can I do it in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xuggler`: http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler

For maven:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
   <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
   <version>5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks Maven :). I was not aware of xuggler. That's a great tool.